# Implementing curl with Node.JS, application just hangs, no response

Tags: node.js, rest, curl, postman

So i am trying to pass a data and use Node to do something very similar to cURL from a Node.JS endpoint.
It hangs, no response, nothing. I don't even see if there is an error or not. It does not respond in Postman. Not sure what the idea is, hence this post.

The data i am sending to POSTman vis json

```
{
  "account_bank":"044",
  "account_number":"0690000040",
  "amount":"700000.25",
  "narration":"test transfer",
  "currency":"NGN",
  "reference":"akhlm-pstmnpyt-rfxx007_PMCKDU_76554",
  "debit_currency":"NGN"
}
```

And the main code. Looks like this :

```
app.post("/api/local-transfers", async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }

    var account_bank = req.body.account_bank;
    var account_number = req.body.account_number;
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var narration = req.body.narration;
    var currency = req.body.currency;
    var reference = req.body.refernce;
    var debit_currency = req.body.debit_currency;

    url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        account_bank: account_bank,
        account_number: account_number,
        amount: amount,
        narration: narration,
        currency: currency,
        reference: reference,
        debit_currency: debit_currency,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        if (responseJson === "Transfer Queued Successfully") {
          return res.send({
            error: false,
            data: response.json(),
            message: "OK",
          });
        }
      });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

It just hangs, No response in postman. What could be wrong?

**Edit**

The `.catch` as requested looks like this

```
app.post("/api/local-transfers", async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }

    var account_bank = req.body.account_bank;
    var account_number = req.body.account_number;
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var narration = req.body.narration;
    var currency = req.body.currency;
    var reference = req.body.refernce;
    var debit_currency = req.body.debit_currency;

    url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        account_bank: account_bank,
        account_number: account_number,
        amount: amount,
        narration: narration,
        currency: currency,
        reference: reference,
        debit_currency: debit_currency,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        if (responseJson === "Transfer Queued Successfully") {
          return res.send({
            error: false,
            data: response.json(),
            message: "OK",
          });
        }
      }).catch(error=>{ //added this catch here.
        throw error;
      });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I am assuming you are using node-fetch in which case the fetch function is asynchronous so when the fetch errors out there is no response sent back. Add a `.catch` onto the fetch call and check if it is erroring out

Comment: @Salim, added that, still the same. Mind if i share source??

Comment: i think your  if (responseJson === "Transfer Queued Successfully")  is not executing. console log inside if condition and check its going inside if condition or not.. if not then it means you are not sending any response back.

Comment: @MuhammadFazeel, the responseJson does not work, truly. What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it to work.
just happened to do some read ups on my side. The mistake was , with `responseJson` it was not executing anything inside of that area,hence changing it, i managed to get it running. So change the fetch from

```
url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        account_bank: account_bank,
        account_number: account_number,
        amount: amount,
        narration: narration,
        currency: currency,
        reference: reference,
        debit_currency: debit_currency,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        if (responseJson === "Transfer Queued Successfully") {
          return res.send({
            error: false,
            data: response.json(),
            message: "OK",
          });
        }
      });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```

To this :

```
app.post("/api/local-transfers", async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith("Bearer ") ||
      !req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
    ) {
      return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please Provide Token!" });
    }

    var account_bank = req.body.account_bank;
    var account_number = req.body.account_number;
    var amount = req.body.amount;
    var narration = req.body.narration;
    var currency = req.body.currency;
    var reference = req.body.refernce;
    var debit_currency = req.body.debit_currency;

    url = "https://api.flutterwave.com/v3/transfers";
    fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-72fe360edef17334f4817a17407011bb-X",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        account_bank: account_bank,
        account_number: account_number,
        amount: amount,
        narration: narration,
        currency: currency,
        reference: reference,
        debit_currency: debit_currency,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        return res.send({ error: false, data: json, message: "OK" });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
});
```